# Load denied by X-Frame-Options while render google share with angularjs

Tags: javascript, google-plus

Getting Load denied by xframe options when i am trying to render google plus share with below code.

```
var options = {
  href: 'http://localhost:4000/'
};
gapi.plus.render('googlePlusBtn', options);
```

The 'googlePlusBtn' is the id of the div element that acts as container for share button.

Link to jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/99307cj3/13/

How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to not put the page you want to share in a frame (that includes putting it on JS Fiddle which uses frames).

Comment: My actual application don't have any frames.I used jsfiddle just to share the code what i was trying.

Comment: @user995478 — If your actual site doesn't have any frames, then the attempt to load the content wouldn't be denied by x-frames-options!

Comment: There are 2 ways to render gplus share button. one with html and other with javascript. When i used html its working fine. But the issue is with the javascript way of implementing. I have no idea what could be the reason for the issue?